# Spring webflux ContextPropogation

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am trying to figure out if I can use the micrometer ContextPropogation to store a user-id from the request using a web filter and then use this context in an entity callback of R2DBC to set the user id before storing into the database.

Is this the right approach? if yes how can I achieve it ?